# MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Consider:

```
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {

  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}, function(err, post) {
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  });

});
```

This is what used to work for me, using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) and [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29). How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like they dropped support for callbacks. They throw an error on purpose, can be seen [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L2130). You have to use async/await as shown in their [example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#example).

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has removed callbacks from its Node.js driver as of version 5.0. See *[findOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.0/classes/Collection.html#findOne)*.

If you really need to use callbacks instead of promises, you will need to use an older version of the driver.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution thanks to my friend @Sean. Instead of the callback function, I have to replace it with a .then() function:

```
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {

  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}).then(post => {

    res.render("post", {

      title: post.title,

      content: post.content
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Who is "Sean"? Does it refer to an answer or comment on this page?

Answer (score 0):

In version `5.0`, MongoDB has removed callbacks from its `node.js` driver. So now you can leverage the `Promise` instead of callback.

Updated Code:

```
Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}).then(post =>{
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
      });
    });
```

Also Refer: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.0/classes/Collection.html#findOne

Comment: You ought to use your own words, not copy verbatim from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616051/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback/75618672#75618672). Otherwise, it is plagiarism. ***"MongoDB has removed callbacks from its Node.js driver"*** is the exact same.