# Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback. Please see my code

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Consider:

```
app.post("/Signup", (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body
    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(user) {
            res.send({message: "User already registered"})
        } else {
            const user = new User ({
                name,
                email,
                password
            })
            user.save(err => {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err)
                } else {
                    res.send({message: "Successfully Registered"})
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

I'm getting the error from *[findOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.0/classes/Collection.html#findOne)* in Mongoose. How can I to fix this bug?

It's a real problem. There is this error which says call back problem that is no longer supported. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

In version `5.0`, MongoDB has removed callbacks from its `node.js` driver. So now you can leverage the `Promise` instead of callback.

Updated Code:

```
 User.findOne({email: email}.then(user => {
    if(user){
        res.send({message: "User already registered"})
    } else {
        const user = new User ({
            name,
            email,
            password
           })
           user.save(err => {
            if(err){
                res.send(err)
            } else {
                res.send({message:"Successfully Registered"})
            }
           })
    }
   })
```

Also Refer: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.0/classes/Collection.html#findOne

Comment: The exact same text is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616051/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback/75656119#75656119) (part of which seems to be have been copied from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616051/mongooseerror-model-findone-no-longer-accepts-a-callback/75618672#75618672)).