# mongodb with nodejs connect error after upgrading

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Well all of my old code worked, until I upgraded to the new community edition and my new ubuntu server, so I reinstalled and upgraded everything, the basic examples should work. I can edit the database and connect locally via mongosh and via mongoDB compass and execute commands, but when I try to connect to the database via nodejs I get no action.

mongo logs attached and server.js snippet

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-25T02:11:42.078+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn12","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"100.147.123.101:46508","extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-25T02:11:42.088+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn13","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"100.147.123.101:60737","extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-25T02:11:49.466+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"100.211.109.11:38048","uuid":"c292f9b4-dc37-4d8d-b523-b12fbd6c51cc","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":13}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-25T02:11:49.466+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"100.211.109.11:38048","client":"conn14","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.1.0"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.15.0-67-generic"},"platform":"Node.js v19.8.1, LE (unified)|Node.js v19.8.1, LE (unified)"}}}
```

```
var Murl = "mongodb://admin:password@100.000.000.000:27017/";

//var Murl = "mongodb+srv://admin:password@100.000.000.000:27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.8.0&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&tls=false";


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
//const Murl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
//const Murl = new MongoClient(url);

//useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, appName: 'mongosh+1.8.0', authMechanism:'DEFAULT', tls: false
function createDoc(datab, c, o){
  console.log(Murl+datab)
  MongoClient.connect(Murl+datab, { },function(err, db) { console.log('this is db: '+db);
    console.log('trying to create a doc inside the function');
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db(datab);
  dbo.collection(c).insertOne(o, function(err, res) {
    console.log('this is error in collection');
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});
}


createDoc('apmsg', 'inmates', {pass: '1231233', credits: 98899});
```

Im at a total loss at this point. There is something simple that I am missing.

the config file is as follows:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Which version of the driver?  Note that with the newest driver the [connect](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.1/classes/MongoClient.html#connect) method does not accept a callback

Comment: Im assuming the newest driver as everything I just installed was fresh and the latest stable. I will try it without a callback

Comment: post for credit for the answer, didnt think they got rid of callbacks in the newest version. need to send you some redbull or something

Comment: That answer already exists is several places, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/75618672/2282634